# Reduce opacity of anchor attribute underline in HTML

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

Is their anyway to use CSS attributes on a HTML class to reduce the opacity/visibility of the default **underline** (not the text, just the underline) on `<a>` tags?

My current relevant Jekyll `default.html` and `style.scss` at the moment looks like this:

```
<h1 class="project-name"><a href="https://itspugle.ga">{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }}</a></h1>`
```

and

```
---
---

@import 'jekyll-theme-cayman';
.project-name a {
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Instead of relying on an underline, use a pseudo-element with  a bottom border that has reduced opacity or an RGBA value with an alpha of less than 1.

Comment: @Terry I'm not confident with CSS or SASS, so I don't understand what you mean by pseudo-element. Could you give me an example of some SASS I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You can use the css **text-decoration-color** property.

**Example:**

```
.project-name a {
   text-decoration: underline;
   -webkit-text-decoration-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4); /* Safari */   
   text-decoration-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

---

**Solution 2:**

If you want more control just eliminate the default underline and use border to control the color and opacity. The upside of this you get to apply different colors for your link text and underline as well.

**Example:**

```
.project-name a {
   text-decoration: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Whilst using the text-decoration attribute adds an underline permanently, the rgba changes work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

For white color and white, 50% opacity underline use:

```css
p {
  background-color: #666;
  padding: 100px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#">example</a>
</p>
```

Code sample from W3Schools [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-decoration-color.asp)
More info from W3C [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/)

Comment: I've just tried that and now the underline always shows, even when you aren't hovering over the hyperlinked text. Even `.project-name a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-decoration-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}` doesn't work

Comment: Try adding `text-decoration: none` to `.project-name a:link`

Comment: basically you need to declare the underline on regular anchor but make it totally hidden with opacity 0% in rgba and change color on hover

Comment: Using `.project-name a {
    color: white;
}

.project-name a:hover {
    text-decoration-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}` worked just fine for me now! Cheers, though

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-decoration` and use rgba to add an opacity to your existing color. In this, I just dropped the opacity of blue.

```css
a {
  text-decoration-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hello, World!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way now with CSS variables

```css
a {
 --color1: 251, 0, 0;
  
  color: rgba(var(--color1), 1);
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: rgba(var(--color1), .33);
}
```

See [pen](https://codepen.io/ShaggyDude/pen/YzVjjOw?editors=1100)